# Does googles guava have a java tryparse integer method or something similar?

Tags: java, guava

I have the java guava library, and was wondering if they have a tryparse type helper method that will attempt to parse a string to a integer, and return a boolean if it failed.

In c#, I can do:

```
if(int.tryparse("somestring", out myInt)) {

}
```

Was hoping java has something similiar (don't want to re-invent the wheel if it exists).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Guava has [Ints.tryParse(String)](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse(java.lang.String)) as of 11.0. It doesn't work quite like the C# method (no out parameters) though. It returns an `Integer` that's `null` if the string couldn't be parsed, so for your example you'd use it like this:

```
Integer myInt = Ints.tryParse(someString);
if (myInt != null) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this was set to be added to release 11.  The status is set to fixed, which I would think means it's either in the current release or will be in the next.

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=660

EDIT:  It is in the API for 11: [tryParse](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: btw, could I jump to the source code from the documentation?  or is the only way to go to browse source and find the method?

Comment: If you click on the name of the method, in the "detailed" section of the Javadoc, it'll go straight to the source...though it's not particularly useful for this specific case.